# How to make IPython Notebook not show results of the previous session?

Tags: python, ipython

Is there a way to make IPython Notebook not show the results of the previous session upon opening an existing notebook? It's not a big deal, but it's fairly annoying to have to scroll through the notebook and manually hide all of my results after starting it so I don't have to scroll for five minutes looking for a specific line. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clear all cell numbers and output from an existing notebook in IPython Notebook:

1. Open the notebook from the IPython Notebook interface by clicking it.
2. From the menu bar select *Cell* -> *All Output* -> *Clear*.